# Convert numpy array to pandas in multiple jumps, or columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, web-scraping

I wrote some simple python code (using Beautiful Soup module) to scrap data off a website. The data I have extracted into a numpy array of the form below

```
array(['Aug 18, 2018', '1.989', '1.989', '1.989', '1.989', '0.81%',
       'Aug 17, 2018', '1.973', '2.016', '2.016', '1.967', '-0.20%',
       'Aug 16, 2018', '1.977', '1.994', '1.996', '1.962', '0.87%',
```

I would like to convert them into a panda dataframe for easier calculation. The trouble is that, the way I have downloaded the data, it is the 1st and every 7th data point onwards is the date, the 2nd and every 8th data point onwards is the base value for that date.

Is there a way to copy values in a 1-d numpy array such that I can specify a variable offset into different columns in pandas such as the below

```
date      start      end         high        low        change
'Aug 18  '1.989'     '1.989'     '1.989'     '1.989'     '0.81%'
'Aug 17  '1.973'     '2.016'     '2.016'     '1.967'     '-0.20%'
'Aug 16  '1.977'     '1.994'     '1.996'     '1.962'     '0.87%'
'Aug 15  '1.960'     '1.995'     '1.995'     '1.958'     '-0.46%'
'Aug 14  '1.969'     '1.958'     '1.969'     '1.948'     '0.97%'
'Aug 13  '1.950'     '1.974'     '1.974'     '1.945'     '-0.61%'
'Aug 12  '1.962'     '1.950'     '1.962'     '1.950'     '-0.61%'
'Aug 11  '1.974'     '1.951'     '1.974'     '1.951'     '0.46%'
'Aug 10  '1.965'     '1.982'     '1.982'     '1.965'     '-1.40%'
```

My code as per below

```
import requests
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

data = np.array([])

#OpenURL
url = requests.get('https://www.investing.com/rates-bonds/australia-1-year-bond-yield-historical-data',headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

#DETERMINE FORMAT
content_page = soup(url.content,'html.parser')

containers = content_page.findAll('table', {'class':'genTbl closedTbl historicalTbl'})
for table in containers:
    for td in table.findAll('td'):
        #print(td.text)
        data = np.append(data, td.text)

data
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you know the number of columns, just use `reshape`:

```
pd.DataFrame(data.reshape(-1, 6), columns=['date', 'start', 'end', 'high', 'low', 'change'])
```

```
           date  start    end   high    low  change
0  Aug 18, 2018  1.989  1.989  1.989  1.989   0.81%
1  Aug 17, 2018  1.973  2.016  2.016  1.967  -0.20%
2  Aug 16, 2018  1.977  1.994  1.996  1.962   0.87%
```

Answer (score 0):

use this, for my own and other people's reference

```
pd_data = pd.DataFrame(index = [0], columns = ['date', 'start', 'end', 'high', 'low'])

for row in range(0, len(data), 6):
    pd_data.loc[row, 'date'] = data[row] #date
    pd_data.loc[row, 'start'] = data[row+1] #start
    pd_data.loc[row, 'end'] = data[row+2] #end
    pd_data.loc[row, 'high'] = data[row+3] #end
    pd_data.loc[row, 'low'] = data[row+4] #end

pd_data
```